# Git no longer detecting file changes in repo

Tags: git, github

I've been working in a repo for a long time and have created many new branches.

Today I created a new branch as normal `git checkout -b new-branch` and made some changed to a file - a file I have worked on many times. However when I ran `git status` no changes were detected.

I ran `git pull origin master` against the branch, but still no changes.

I restarted my machine and created a brand new branch, but had the same problem.

I also tried to checkout and existing branch and make changes there - still git doesn't detect anything.

Would anyone know what's going on and how I could fix it?

Edit- Commands used:

```
git checkout -b new branch
git pull origin master
*make changes to file*
git status (shows no changes)
git pull origin master (shows no conflicts)
git commit -m "test" ('nothing to commit')
git push origin stg (Success - everyting up to date. No changes appear on branch in Github)
```

Comment: Can you post the commands used and their outputs?

Comment: Did you update your `.gitignore`?

Comment: Also make sure you're still executing your commands from the repo root.

Comment: @liuyihe no .gitignore has not been touched

Comment: @RomainValeri Yes commands are executed from the root

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've added the commands I've used above

Comment: Whats it the output of `git diff`?

Answer (score 1):

> no .gitignore has not been touched

Still, you can check if the file is marked as ignored by any .gitignore directive with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the error `error: unknown option 'path/to/file'`. I couldn't find anything on Google about this one

Comment: @MeltingDog Just to be sure, you did replace `path/to/file` by the actual path to the actual file  which is no longer changing, right?

Comment: Hi @VonC Yes I did that

Comment: @MeltingDog Are you on Windows?

Comment: I'm on virtual box running Linux